# set language android to php-mysqli

Tags: php, android, mysqli

I have an android application, that makes a connection to a PHP-script, which then fetches data from a database and returns the result. It all works fine and dandy, except for language-settings. I have set the language to dainsh and UTF-8, all the places I can think of, and when I send it to the database it is in danish, but the returnvalue is not in danish.
Here is my call to the PHP-script from android

```
  URL url = new URL(selectUrl);
                HttpURLConnection httpUrlConncetion = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpUrlConncetion.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpUrlConncetion.setDoInput(true);
                httpUrlConncetion.setConnectTimeout(10000);
                httpUrlConncetion.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "da_DK");
                httpUrlConncetion.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/json");
                httpUrlConncetion.connect();

                String line = "";
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                int Httpresult = httpUrlConncetion.getResponseCode();
                Log.d(TAG, httpUrlConncetion.getResponseMessage().toString());
                if (Httpresult == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    InputStream inputStream = httpUrlConncetion.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));


                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line);
                        list.add(line);
                    }
                    result=sb.toString();

                    for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
                        Log.d(TAG, "min nye list" + list.get(i) + "\n");
                    }
```

and the Logcat says

[image]
it is ,"minegen":"n\u00f8gler"} that is the problem. it should have been the danish "nøgler".
The php has been set like this in the connection-file to the database:
"mysqli_set_charset($con, "utf8");

and the mysqli-database has been set to danish language - like this

[image]

And I do get danish characters in the table when checking in the table
[image]

So what am I missing??
Any help would be highly appreciated :)

Comment: I think it is not the mysqli, but PHP encoding. try setting mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");

Comment: That looks like an escaped unicode character. Try the `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` flag on `json_encode`. http://php.net/json_encode

Answer (score 0):

I once run into a issue like this it was about saving emojis like you i had all charset set correctly but no matter what i did it didn't work so finaly  i end up using urlencode($content) when saving into my database and urldecode($content) when retrieving data

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like this for Persian characters and I solved it by bad way which worked for me. I just defined my own encoding and made two functions `FAtoEN(s)` and `ENtoFA(s)`. `FAtoEN` changes each Persian char to an English char using keyboard keys. for example changes "ن" to "k" because I use k key on keyboard when the keyboard is persian and I want to write ن. and also the other function do this inverse.